# The web page loses connection after a query which is also unsuccessful

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**"This site can’t be reached The connection was reset."** is the result after I submit my registration form.

This is my controller:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    LoginModel init = new LoginModel();

    switch(action){
        case "register": {
                LoginModel.r_fname = request.getParameter("fname");
                LoginModel.r_mname = request.getParameter("mname");
                LoginModel.r_lname = request.getParameter("lname");
                LoginModel.r_username = request.getParameter("r_username");
                LoginModel.r_password = request.getParameter("r_password");

                out.print(init.register());  
                if(LoginModel.register()){
                    out.print("yey");
                }

                break;
            }
        case "login": {
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                if (username.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) {
                    response.sendRedirect("/practice/");
                } else {

                }       
                break;
            }
        default:
            out.print("Action unidentified");
            break;
    }

}
```

And this here is my model:

```
 public Boolean register(){
    Boolean bool = false;

    try {
        query = "INSERT INTO name(fname, mname, lname) VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
        pstmt = conn.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, "qwe");
        pstmt.setString(2, "qwe");
        pstmt.setString(3, "qwe");  
        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        bool = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    return bool;
}
```

So when i change my model into public String and print **"Lorem"**, it works. However, in this phase, it loses the connection and the webpage returns **"This site can’t be reached The connection was reset"**

Comment: Are there any exceptions or errors in the logs?

Comment: when using the IDE sir, there are none

Comment: testing the file in the IDE works fine

Comment: "The web application [/practice] is still processing a request that has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.", i found one

Comment: I'm not sure then, sorry. If I were you, I'd start with some logging so that you can trace through the program and try to figure out where exactly it's getting stuck.